# Ranged Solr Queries on timestamp field

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm trying to build a solr query for timecode values with the following format:

```
run_time:

00:25:00

00:30:00

01:00:00
```

I'd like to filter a range of timecodes. Everything 30 minutes or under, for example.

I've tried a couple of queries with no success.

```
run_time:[* TO 00:30:00]

run_time:[* TO 00\:30\:00]

run_time:[* TO *00:31:00Z]
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Read [here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/working-with-dates.html) for more details about solr date operations:

```
 run_time:[ NOW-30MINUTES TO NOW ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - this doesn't appear to have worked. Wouldn't the NOW value correlate to the current time of day?

Answer (score 1):

Your use case appears to be searching for processes which ran for 30 minutes or less. Date field will not be the right fit here.
A better approach would be to store the run time information in a number field.

```
run_time: 
25
30
60
```

The you can use a range query on this field to get desired results.

```
runtime:[0 TO 30]
```

This will fetch records having runtime between 0 to 30minutes including 0,30